# Add Checkbox to data table

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatables

I need to add a checkbox to my dataTable, I've looked over the example at dataTables.net and couldn't get it to work. I know I can add an input box to a table with render so it should be similar. I have also tried several examples from JSFiddle and SO. Here's what I have so far, some details omitted for brevity. Rest assured this is the sixth column. Data is being retrieved successfully via ajax. The table displays, but the sixth column is empty where there should be a check box. I have tried https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html

and

https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/07Lrpqm7/

```
  $('#table').DataTable({
"ajax": "http://localhost:8080/test/static/json/data.json",
"initComplete": function(){

    $("#datepicker-start").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
            app.oldDate(dateText); 
        }
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date(app.oldDate()));
},
"type": "GET",
"paging":false,
"language": {
    "emptyTable":"No Date."
},
"pageLength":-1,
"lengthMenu":[[5,10,25,-1], [5,10,25,"All"]],
"dom":'<"filterBox"f><"topi>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
"columnDefs":[
 {
    "targets": 4,
    "data": null,
    "orderable": false,

}
,{
    "render": function(data){
        return "<input type='checkbox' checked: flag/>";
    },
    "targets": 6,
    "visible":true,
    "orderable": false,

}
,{
    "width": "30px",
    "render": function(data){
        return '<div id="arrow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></div>';
    },
    targets: 7
}
]
,"columns": [
{"data":"result"},
{"data":"assignedTo"},
{"data":"assignee"},
{"data":"startDate"},
{

    "data": "dueDate",
    "render": function(data){
        app.oldDate(data);
        return '<label for="datepicker-start" class="input-group-addon hide">Date</label>\
        <input type="text" id="datepicker-start" placeholder="Start Date" />\
         '
     },


    "orderable": false

    }
    ,{"data":"oldDate"},
    {
        "data":'' ,
        "orderable": false,
    }
    ,{
        "data":'' ,
        "orderable": false,
    }
    ]
```

});
Html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Checkbox</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: could you please give an example for one row of adding checkbox, as there are already 7 columns with checkbox at firstline

Comment: You misunderstand, I just need to put a checkbox in a single cell. There are no other checkboxes. The other rows are filled with text data.

Comment: in your columns section, do you have {data:null} for the checkbox column?

Comment: I would like to see your whole data table definition

Comment: I have added the entire table definition as requested. The checkbox in the one column (6) does not show